# How to selected the first row on the tableview ,default

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

How to selected the first row on the tableview ,default

Answer (score 3):

```
  [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```